# MimeType Desktop entry for all image files

Tags: images, mime-types

I want a desktop entry like `MimeType=image/ETC` to create a context menu action in Dolphin (File Manager in Linux Mint KDE) that would appear only for images.

[image]

To the question *["Is there a generic mime-type for all image files](https://superuser.com/q/979135/162573)"* the answer seems to be no.

On the other hand, for my limited purpose of editing a `.desktop` file in Linux Mint KDE to create an 'Action' context-menu entry in Dolphin File Manager that would be shown only for image files, there is a solution that was indicated in a comment to the linked question.

I am creating this question to make that solution available here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There [are](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=94845) [indications](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1917702), that the entry `MimeType=image/*` would do the trick:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Convert
Exec=convert.sh
MimeType=image/*;
```